# Can I filter MQ "display queue" on NOT some queue names?

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm losing my ever-loving mind over this one.

I'm trying to output a list of local queues with their current depth and maximum depth. The following command basically does the job:

```
display qlocal(*) curdepth maxdepth
```

However, I'm getting all the SYSTEM.* queues and I don't want them in the list. Theoretically I can use the where( ) filter to do this, but it seems like this most useful function is just not possible because...

```
display qlocal(*) where(???? nl 'SYSTEM*') curdepth maxdepth
```

...what do I put for ????  I've tried all sorts including the seemingly obvious 'queue' but nothing works. Am I stuck with separately processing the output (a chore at the best of times due to its horrid formatting) to rid myself of these?

Comment: Not supported better use MQSCX product from MQGem or do your parsing in the script.

Comment: Thanks. I had hoped that wasn't the case. Looks like I'll be parsing. :-(

Comment: If you want to exclude system objects specifically, you could filter on crdate and crtime. As system objects are typically the first to be created, I see them usually having the same crdate and crtime values and those values being before any of the other objects.

Comment: @AttilaRepasi ooh, that's a clever approach! Unfortunately it looks like some version upgrades have introduced new queues and therefore I have some SYSTEM queues newer than some of our original user queues. We've gone 5.3 -> 6.0 -> 7.0 -> 7.1 over 14 years. :-(

Comment: I have managed to process the output enough that I can now exclude the SYSTEM queues as a final step.

Answer (score 1):

The command below might help. As you can't filter using the queue name in the 'where' parameter, the best solution would be to parse the output. The below command basically formats the mqsc object output to single lines and the egrep removes everything that starts with SYSTEM.

```
echo "dis ql(*) curdepth maxdepth" | runmqsc QMNAME |  sed 's/^[^  ].*$/%/g' | tr -s " " | tr -d "\n" | tr "%" "\n" | egrep -v "^ QUEUE\(SYSTEM"
```

Comment: Hi Enio Marques Junior. Please consider adding an explanation.

Comment: Thanks, this got me exactly what I wanted

Comment: Thanks, this got me exactly what I wanted. @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 the first "sed" says "replace any lines that DONT start with double space ('  ') with a literaly '%' ", which essentially strips all the garbage output, but also set a "linebreak" to group each of the outputs.  

Next, strip all the padding whitespace (leave 1 space).  

Next, remove all new lines.  
  
Finally, turn '%' into new lines

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is an old question and your problem is already solved, but since someone mentioned you can do this with MQSCX, I thought I would add an answer for future readers. With [MQSCX](https://www.mqgem.com/mqscx.html) you can issue the following command to achieve what you want.

```
DISPLAY QLOCAL(*) CURDEPTH MAXDEPTH =WHERE(QUEUE NL 'SYSTEM*')
```

The `=WHERE` clause was added to MQSCX to counteract some of the restrictions that the IBM MQ `WHERE` clause has.